# Retrieving full namespace of property referenced in Expression<Func<>> predicate

Tags: c#

I'm currently building a fluent API that works in the following manner:

```
this.Property(x => x.Address).Display("Postal Address");
```

As I need to reference this data at a later date, I would like to add it to a dictionary where the key is the format of `ClassName.PropertyName` (this seems the most reliable way to retrieve the data at a later date - though I'm most certainly open to suggestions if there is a better way).

For example, if I have a class like below:

```
namespace ExampleProject.Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class ExampleViewModel
    {
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The key for the Address property would be the namespace followed by the property name, like so: `ExampleProject.Demo.ViewModels.Address.ExampleViewModel`.

However I'm having difficulty getting this full information via reflection from the expression that's passed into the `Property(x => x)` method above. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to how I can retrieve this data from the Property method's argument?

The signature of the `Property` method is the following:

```
public PropertyInstance<TProp> Property<TProp>(Expression<Func<TModel, TProp>> expression) where TProp : class
{
    ...  
}
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will retrieve the property:

```
var property = (PropertyInfo)(((MemberExpression)expression.Body).Member);
```

From this, you can retrieve the following:

```
property.Name
property.DeclaringType.FullName or AssemblyQualifiedName
```

I'd rather use `Type.AssemblyQualifiedName` in your key than the namespaced name, in case you have different assemblies containing the same type.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for thank you, and thank you for your `AssemblyQualifiedName` recommendation.